# wxEVT_ENTER_WINDOW doesn't change button background color

Tags: wxpython

I want my code to change button background color when mouse cursor is over the button to "yellow" and to green when mouse cursor is moved off of the button.

Using wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW to change button background color to "yellow" and wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW to change background color to green.

Below is simple code which includes a frame and a button. Noticed that when mouse was over the button background color didn't change to yellow but when mouse cursor was moved off of the button background color changed to green. So I added SetLabel to display "INSIDE" when cursor was over the button to see if EVT_ENTER_WINDOW was getting fired. When I ran the code, found that INSIDE is displayed when cursor is over the button so EVT_ENTER_WINDOW is getting triggered but background color doesn't change. Why is the button background color not changing ?

```
import wx
def onMouseOverButton(event):
    btn.SetBackgroundColour("yellow")
    btn.SetLabel("INSIDE")

def onMouseLeaveButton(event):
    btn.SetBackgroundColour("green")
    btn.SetLabel("OUTSIDE")

app = wx.App()
win = wx.Frame(None,size=(410,335))
win.Show()
btn = wx.Button(win,  pos=(50,50))
btn.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW,onMouseOverButton)
btn.Bind(wx.EVT_LEAVE_WINDOW,onMouseLeaveButton)
app.MainLoop()
```

Thank you

Comment: You don't state your operating system or the version of wx. On linux, wxpython version 4.1.1 your code works as expected.

Comment: Thank you for feedback.  Using wxPython version 4.1.1 and Windows 10, 20H2 build 19042.928. Good to know it's working OK.

Comment: Interestingly, the button turns yellow if left mouse button is down and will remain yellow as long as left mouse button is held down.

Comment: It all sounds a little odd. Take a look at any desktop themes you have in place or change them and see if the behaviour changes. The fact that the button can and does change colour, under certain circumstances, suggests that something else is in play.